# System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Tags: android

I'm trying to initialize the activityManager like this but  it  failed . here is the code :

```
private ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Can someone tell me why ??

Comment: `but it failed` is not informative at all. Describe your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`private` suggests you're trying to initialize a member variable. `Activity.getSystemService()` requires a properly initialized `Context` and you cannot use an `Activity` as a `Context` until `onCreate()`.

This is also stated in your question title as the exception you're getting, `IllegalStateException` with the helpful message `"System services not available to Activities before onCreate()"`.

To fix it, just move the variable initialization to `onCreate()`.